# gazebo gui camera slows down when zooming out a lot

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm using gazebo version  11 and I noticed that when I zoom out a lot, the ui camera behavior changes :

- when trying to rotate, it rotates around a point in the air,
- same thing happens when trying to move along x,y
- the zoom in and zoom out slows down...

Do you know if there is anyway to suppress this behavior ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28932/gazebo-gui-camera-slows-down-when-zooming-out-a-lot/) by [jeajea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158153/jeajea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I answered on my own after a long time : There were clouds in the sky so each time I went above the clouds , gazebo was focusing on the clouds and not the ground anymore

---

Originally posted by [jeajea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/158153/jeajea/) with karma: 1 on 2023-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0